# No longer array json and how to alert json data in jquery

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

No idea why this no longer array and no comma between {},{}

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo (json_encode($row,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

And how to alert json data in jquery?
Before this I use for loop in js to loop it but for some reason I have to loop in server side now.

Edited

```
//because i want to replace $row['url'] to get_thumb();    
foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
        $row['url'] = $this->vz_image->get_thumb($row['url'],'n');
        header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo (json_encode($row,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }
```

Then I got this result, but I have no idea how to alert this json data in jquery. Any help?

```
{
"id": "44",
"url": "assets\/img\/uploaded_photos\/thumbs\/1358786330_n.jpg",
"created_time": "1358786330",
"photo_id": "170",
"tag_id": "44",
"name": "Lan Yao Yeng",
"num_photo": "3"
}{
"id": "44",
"url": "assets\/img\/uploaded_photos\/thumbs\/1358711532_n.jpg",
"created_time": "1358711532",
"photo_id": "169",
"tag_id": "44",
"name": "Lan Yao Yeng",
"num_photo": "3"
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the `,` to be coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass the entire array to the client, just encode the array itself, not each elements.

```
function map($row){
    if (isset($row['url']))
        $row['url'] = $this->vz_image->get_thumb($row['url'],'n');
    return $row;
}

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode(array_map("map", $query->result_array()),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

If you use this in a class, you may have to change `array_map("map", $query->result_array())` to `array_map(array($this, "map"), $query->result_array())`.

Comment: Can you see again my question?

Comment: This works. You saved me LOL and I learn new thing array_map() Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It isn't an array because you aren't giving it an array.

You're echoing a number of objects one after the other; not an array of objects.

Comment: Can you see again my question?

Comment: You cannot concatenate multiple JSON literals; the result will not be valid JSON.  You need to `json_encode()` the entire array at once.

Comment: But if i json_encode the entire array.  How can I replace the $row['url'] to use php get_thumb() function?